# Проверка загружаемого на сервер файла

Tags: java, java-ee, файлы, servlet, валидация

Добрый день!

Подскажите, как организовать проверку на размер загружаемого на сервер файла. На сервлете устанавливаю ограничение в аннотации:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 2097152)
```

Собственно вопрос, как организовать проверку на размер загружаемого файла на сервер, если файл больше допустимого размера?

Проверяю файл вот так:

```
Part part = null;
try{
    part = request.getPart("photo");
}catch(Exception e){
    LOG.error("Error in getPart");
}
```

Но при загрузку файла размера больше чем ограничение, никаких исключений не вылетает, а вылетает ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED, т.е. сервер не до конца прочитал запрос пользователя. Использую сервер Tomcat 7.

Буду рад любому совету!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если размер файла превышает ограничение, указанное в `@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize)`, то будет выброшено исключение при обращении к методу `HttpServletRequest.getParts()`.

Например, при развёртывании сервлета под управлением сервера приложений `Wildfly 10`, исключение выглядит следующим образом:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000054: The maximum size 10485760 for an individual file in a multipart request was exceeded
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000054: The maximum size 10485760 for an individual file in a multipart request was exceeded
```

Если Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы просто не допустить загрузку больших файлов, то дополнительно делать ничего не обязательно, т.к. процесс будет прерываться на строчке

```
Part part = request.getPart("photo")
```

и не дойдёт до сохранения в БД. Если же требуется дополнительная обработка при получении больших файлов, то следует заключить `getPart` в `try/catch`

**UPDATE**

При развёртывании приложения под управлением Tomcat 7 выбрасываемое исключение выглядит так:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field binaryFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 2097152 bytes.
...
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field binaryFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 2097152 bytes.
```

Вот простейший пример кода, отлавливающего исключение и перенаправляющего пользователя на страницу ошибки:

```
@WebServlet("/file")
@MultipartConfig(
    fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2,
    maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2,
    maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2)
public class FilesServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        for (Part part : req.getParts()) {
            //работа с полученными файлами
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException) {
            resp.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/fileSizeError.html");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: делаю дополнительную обработку, чтобы уведомляла пользователя, что файл больше требуемого, так вот, при загрузке большого файла вылетает ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED, т.е. сервер не до конца прочитал запрос пользователя. Подскажите, как обрабатывать эту ошибку? Использую сервер Tomcat 7.

Comment: Если вы отловите исключение в блоке catch, то оно не должно выбрасываться на клиентскую часть. В блоке catch вы можете реализовать любую требующуюся логику, например, перенаправление на страницу ошибки - resp.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/errormMaxUploadSize.html"), либо осуществить другие манипуляции с ответом. Что именно будет удобнее сделать во многом зависит от того, как реализована клиентская часть (например, какой фреймворк используется). Специфика клиентского фреймворка выходит за рамки заданного вопроса, можете создать новый вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: вы не поняли, я имею в виду, что никаких исключений не вылетает, просто переносит на страницу с ошибкой ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED. Все это я дополнил в вопросе

Comment: Исключение выбрасывается, не знаю почему вы не можете его отловить. Дополнил ответ для Tomcat 7. Если и это не будет работать - берите "чистый" Tomcat, разворачивайте в нём пустое приложение с одним только сервлетом, без каких-либо других классов и библиотек и тестируйте.

Answer (score 1):

Если размер файла больше указанного, то бросится исключение `IllegalStateException`.

```
try {
    parts = request.getPart("photo");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // что-нибудь
}
```

Comment: Что не так? Ответ не верен?

Comment: я не оценивал, но выбрасывает только ошибку err_aborted, данного исключения нет

Comment: Голос против поставила система ([Дух сообщества](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/?tab=profile)). Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.